# Monitoring/logging NFS user interactions

Tags: nfs

This might be simple, but I can't seem to Google it. Basically we have a NFS  folder I'm trying to set up filesystem monitoring/logging for it - which user on which machine adds files, deletes files, etc.

Not sure how to go about this and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control client and they are Linux based hosts, then one option to collect that information is to use [auditd](https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/). You will need to update **/etc/audit/audit.rules** on each client to autid nfs mount point, for example:

```
-w /nfs-mount -p wa -k nfs
```

where `/nfs-mount` is the mount point and `nfs` is the key to use when search the events:

```
# ausearch -k test
```

Unfortunately, auditd doesn't work for servers and you need more sophisticated solutions, like packaet capture. This is an example of displaying uids of users that create files:

```
# tshark -i any -f "port 2049" -Y "nfs.open.opentype == 1" \
      -o nfs.file_name_snooping:true \
      -o nfs.file_full_name_snooping:true \
      -T fields -e rpc.auth.uid -e nfs.name
```